# Vscode interfering with npm GitHub install

Tags: github, npm, visual-studio-code

Today npm started to act up when I executed `npm i <github repo>` inside a VSCode terminal.

The action was interrupted by a VSCode popup window
["Image: The extension GitHub wants to sign in using GitHub."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2q50m.png)

I [Cancel]'ed that popup, but npm still hung.
This time two popups occurred in vscode asking me for username and password.[Image: VSCode input dialogues for username and password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJkR1.png)

I [ESC][ESC]'ed out of those, but the same thing happened a second time.
I avoided that too by doing [Cancel][ESC][ESC] again.

Despite my actions to "ignore" the interruption, the GitHub library actually got installed (Hurray).

Retrying the same install in a terminal outside VSCode, did not show the same interruption.

Does anybody know how I can get rid of this annoying interference from VSCode?
It should be noted that there are no GitHub extension showing in the VSCode extension list.
Is there some internal GitHub extention in VSCode?

I already have perfectly good SSH-key credentials for GitHub that works well with npm outside VSCode. I do not see why I should spread my credentials to VSCode as well.

Regards,
Erik

VSCode 1.48.2,
Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64516243/why-does-vscode-intercepts-git-push-command-on-terminal

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too, and only found suggestion of setting

```
  "github.gitAuthentication": false,
```

This stopped the first popup you describe, but I could still not suppress the second Git username and password dialog. I've found that to stop that, it is also necessary to set:

```
  "git.terminalAuthentication": false,
```

**Note:** The integrated terminal will need to be exited/restarted for this to take effect.

[image]