# why does vscode intercepts git push command on terminal?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

Today I was going to execute `git push` from the **vscode terminal** and a dialog popup saying:

> extension 'GitHub' wants to sign in using GitHub.

[image]

I've checked and turns out that I don't have any extension called GitHub installed on vscode.

The question is why this is showing for me? If I wanted to push using an extension I would not typing on terminal `git push`. Is vscode intercepting what I type in terminal?

Besides that it also opens a user/password dialog like this:
[image]

This is invasive. Is there any way to disable this?

PS: I already uncheck GitHub Authentication from Settings:
[image]

I'm using vscode for one year and this is the first thing that annoyed me. I like vscode very much and I don't want it to became an IDE. Features like this should be incremented by extentions.

PS2: I'm using vscode 1.50.0

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52466989/how-to-change-git-user-in-visual-studio-code-or-even-in-command-line-permissio) answer your question? Not the same issue but related. Did you google this issue? [It is not new](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&ei=wm2UX-OdNZ6SjLsPkp2d-AM&q=%22extension+%27GitHub%27+wants+to+sign+in+using+GitHub%22).

Comment: @RegEdit no, doesn't answer =/
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63740987/6934746) is very similar, but nobody answer. The problem is not why git asks password but why vscode is intercepting the terminal to get the password. I just want to use as if it were a normal terminal where the password should be typed in the terminal.

Comment: I was surprised when this interception happened to me while I was working via Remote-SSH in the vscode terminal.  (I am new to both vscode & git.) Also surprised that push succeeded with simply user+password, I was expecting to have to set up personal access token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour is [built into VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/github), so you will see this prompt even if you do not have a GitHub extension installed:

> Enabling authentication through GitHub happens when you run any Git
> action in VS Code that requires GitHub authentication, such as pushing
> to a repository that you're a member of or cloning a private
> repository. You don't need to have any special extensions installed
> for authentication; it is built into VS Code so that you can
> efficiently manage your repository.
> When you do something that requires GitHub authentication, you'll see
> a prompt to sign in

You can use a separate Windows command prompt to avoid VS Code intercepting your commands.

**EDIT** If you prefer to use VS Code terminal for git commands without the interception, then as HolyBlackCat helpfully points out, there is now a setting to disable this behaviour.

```
"github.gitAuthentication": false,
```

Any git authentication prompts will then occur outside VS Code.

Comment: Can't check right now, but I thought `"github.gitAuthentication": false` disables this?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat you are right, just tried it and it works--that is great news and I've updated my answer to include this.

Comment: `"github.gitAuthentication": false,` does not work for me (when using more complex toolchain in the VSCode CLI). It still asks for login/password. Version: 1.53.0 @ macOS Big Sur

Comment: Did not work for me.